# How to get Laravel to use the upgraded MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My Laravel box was using MySQL 5.6.41:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.11 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> DB::connection()->getPdo()
=> PDO {#2943
     inTransaction: false,
     attributes: {
       CASE: NATURAL,
       ERRMODE: EXCEPTION,
       AUTOCOMMIT: 1,
       PERSISTENT: false,
       DRIVER_NAME: "mysql",
       SERVER_INFO: "Uptime: 71185  Threads: 1  Questions: 2555  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 103  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 82  Queries per second avg: 0.035",
       ORACLE_NULLS: NATURAL,
       CLIENT_VERSION: "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $",
       SERVER_VERSION: "5.6.41",  <<<--- This is the MySQL version
       STATEMENT_CLASS: [
         "PDOStatement",
       ],
       EMULATE_PREPARES: 0,
       CONNECTION_STATUS: "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP",
       DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE: BOTH,
     },
   }
```

I upgraded the MySQL version to 5.7.24 using `yum`:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

However, when I check the version through Laravel, it is still the same.

I've checked the `.env` file for variables that have a value of `5.6.41` or an absolute path to a mysql executable, but have found nothing. As such, I would assume it would just pick up the same version I do when I run `which mysql`. However, this is not the case.

I have also tried `composer dump-autoload` in case it just needed to be refreshed, but it didn't help.

This is running on an ec2 box with AWS Linux.

How can I get Laravel to use the same version of MySQL I get when I run `which mysql`?

#### Edit:

`sudo service mysqld restart` did not do the trick.

After talking with a colleague, it seems that what I have accomplished is updating the client, but the database itself is still not upgraded. I will update later if that turned out to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Do you have restarted mysql daemon?

Comment: @loic.lopez Good idea! I'll look up how to do that.

Comment: check in config/database.php what variables are set. Because there are some default values that laravel will use if it can't read the .env file ...